# how to connect input values

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to connect these 2 input values together so when i move the range input the other input changes accordingly and when user types the range adjusts accordingly

I have already tried various stuff but I keep coming back to this

```
 <style>
 .slidecontainer {
 width: 100%;
 }

.slider {
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
background: #d3d3d3;
outline: none;
opacity: 0.7;
-webkit-transition: .2s;
transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
background: #4CAF50;
cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
background-image: url("Olive.png");
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<input>

<div class="slidecontainer">
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

Comment: _“I have already tried various stuff”_ - then please _show_ what you have tried next time.

Comment: The code I have pasted is what I have tried if you are one of the down voters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onchange` events to change the values of both the inputs insync

```js
var ele1 = document.querySelector('#a')
var ele2 = document.querySelector('#myRange')

function a() {
  ele2.value = ele1.value;
}

function b() {
  ele1.value = ele2.value
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url("Olive.png");
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="a" onchange="a()">
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange" onchange="b()">
</div>
```